# Separating messages in Protocol Buffers

Tags: networking, protocol-buffers

I am building an UDP messaging system with Protocol Buffers. I have several messages (e.g. ChannelUpdate, MessageCreate, ACK). If I send a message to the remote, how can I also send what type of message I am sending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to always send the same message type: a root message that *has* one of the others. For example:

```proto
message SomeRoot {
  oneof content {
    ChannelUpdate channelUpdate = 1;
    MessageCreate msgCreate = 2;
    // etc
  }
}
```

Now you're using an inbuilt protocol feature to enforce the logic.